# Why do I have a error when I use help me please keycloak.init?

Tags: javascript, numa

how can I solve this problem?
help me please
keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(function () {}

TypeError: keycloak.init is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
const keycloak = Keycloak('./public/keycloak.json');
```

Try this:

```
const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
```

and set promiseType to native in the init options like this(in your case) :

```
keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required', promiseType: 'native'}).then(authenticated => {
   this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated })
 })
```

Share
E

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
const keycloak = Keycloak('./public/keycloak.json');
```

Try this:

```
const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
```

and set promiseType to native in the init options like this(in your case) :

```
keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required', promiseType: 'native'})
.then(authenticated => { this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated }) })
```